# Automatic Closing Program For Every Resolution

Tags: c++, screen, mouse, center, centering

I'm an enthousiast programmer and I just started with some basic's that my friend learned me. (Things like:' keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0); ' and    X++;
            SetCursorPos(X, Y);
            Sleep(1);)
But I have a problem with my program, I want to make my program for every screen resolution. Not only for my 1600x900. I tried many things as "GetDesktopResolution(horizontal, vertical);" and "GetWindowRect" but that didn't help. I have made a code for my resolution and it worked but the thing I typed in can't work with people that have 1910x1075 or something like that. So I want it automaticly detect the screen and run the program and shut down the pc. The biggest problem is to center my mouse so it can go to the middle of X-lenght and then to the middle of Y-Lenght. Here is my code for my resolution (1600x900):

```
int main()
{
    while (X < 800)
    {
        X++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (X < 450)
    {
        Y++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (X < 1600)
    {
        X++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y < 900)
    {
        Y++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (X > 800)
    {
        X--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y > 450)
    {
        Y--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (X > 1)
    {
        X--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y > 1)
    {
        Y--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);`enter code here`
    }
    while (X < 1589)
    {
        X++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    void left_click()
        ;
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0); //Clicks to close program
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    while (X < 800)
    {
        X++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y < 450)
    {
        Y++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (X < 1600)
    {
        X++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y < 900)
    {
        Y++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (X > 800)
    {
        X--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y > 450)
    {
        Y--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (X > 1)
    {
        X--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y > 1)
    {
        Y--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y < 900)
    {
        Y++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    void right_click()
        ;
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0); //Right clicks on windows icon
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    while (Y > 862)
    {
        Y--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (X < 378)
    {
        X++;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    while (Y > 835)
    {
        Y--;
        SetCursorPos(X, Y);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    void left_click()
        ;
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0); //Clicks on Shut Down
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: This program does *NOT* compile. Google for "stackoverlow MCVE" and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

For getting sizes of the screen in MSWindows you can use GetDeviceCaps function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx